# Background image headache

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to place my logo into a div / span tag / h1 tag ( anywhere really )

I'm trying to load the image using CSS. I'm nearly sure i've done this many times before.. but for some reason it's not working this time.

CSS

```
.logo{
background-image:url(../img/logo-6.png);
width:400px;
height:75px;
}
```

It's simple. nothing special. I know the path to the image is correct. I was coding in Sublime text.. but moved to Dreamweaver when this didn't work. When i hover over the image URL in Dreamweaver it shows my image.. so it's the correct path.

HTML

```
<span class="logo"></span>
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Thats just two example of what i'm trying. I've no content in the span or div and I won't use both once I get one working.

the width and height that i've set are the correct size that the image is.

Why won't it appear as a background image in the div / span ?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the url in double quotes? `background-image:url("../img/logo-6.png");
`

Comment: Yes. I've tired double and single quotes. Didn't work. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The image url could be  wrong. Try to open it in a web browser. What is the status code of the response?

Comment: There's nothing 'wrong' with your code, it works fine as I've tested it and replaced the image URL with something else... Is there another CSS style that's also using the .logo class elsewhere overriding this? It's that, or your image url / location is wrong?

Comment: Maybe you have another CSS breaking your height/width. In the `<span>` case is normal, an inline empty element has no width / height. But in the case of `<div>` it's more strange, so you have another code that is overriding the div tag.  See this fiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/mzvpc885/** you only see the div and the displayed span, but the first span is `0x0` size

Comment: could you provide any screenshots from your browser's console or network tabs? also could you post your code in fiddle? because I tryied your code and everything works fine.

Comment: your code is OK [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7nv2gg1/), try `RootPath` something like this `url("/img/logo-6.png")`

Comment: Check white space on the canvas is it outside of the `h2` tag? can you give it a smaller height and width then add position `left top` to see if its pulling in as could just be a position issue - bit hard to tell without a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your width and height to percentage

```
width: 100%; height: 100%;
```

Or try the background-image without the width and height, and see!

As for the html part:

Try adding the `<img>` inside the `<div>` or the `<span>`
then go to your css and try this:

```
img { width: 100%; height: auto;}
```